# What are the differences when playing as Luigi?

Tags: super-mario-galaxy

After completing *Super Mario Galaxy* with Mario, you gain the option to play through it again as his brother, Luigi.  I've noticed some slight differences between the 2 plumbers, and have been wondering lately if I've got the whole story.
What I've noticed so far is:

- Luigi slides on his heels, as opposed to coming to an abrupt stop when the analog stick is released.
- When doing a spin attack underwater, some of Luigi's air is drained per each spin, where Mario's is not.
- Luigi gets 20 1-Ups from Princess Peach's letters, where Mario gets fewer.

---

Are there any more variations in gameplay between the 2 brothers?  I'm looking for a **complete** list of variances.

Comment: Sigh, the purple coin level on the luigi map....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Alright, I've done some further digging, and these are the differences I've found:

- Uses Air when spinning underwater
- Has less traction, so he slides and skids
- Jumps farther and higher; runs faster
- (perhaps related to the above) knocked back slightly farther when hit, which equates to a longer post-hit stun
- The cosmic Luigi challenge runs take advantage of Luigi's physics, which may mean separate routes than cosmic Mario
- In addition to the above, some galaxies have slightly altered levels, such as the "Luigi meets Luigi" star in Toytime Galaxy, which changes from the 8-bit Mario planet to the backside, which features an 8-bit Luigi (with the change in colors coming from a change in the platform "pixels")
- Mario gets 1-ups from Princess Peach's letters, but Luigi gets 20 1-ups instead (It still says "Dear Mario" Poor guy can't catch a break)

Comment: Just to be clear... is that 20 1-Ups in that last bullet point?

Comment: Yes. I'll clarify that then.

Answer (score 4):

Besides what Raven added, I know that Luigi's cosmic double challenges are significantly more difficult than Mario's.  Also, some of the levels change slightly (such as the 2d Mario one, becomes a 2d Luigi one).

Comment: Are the challenges more difficult?  How so?

Comment: @GnomeSlice: The Cosmic Double takes a lot more shortcuts.

Comment: > Well, if you edit Raven's info into your question, I'll accept your answer.  :)